# Merge different Keras models into ONE

Tags: python, merge, keras, model, lstm

I'm trying to forecast time series using LSTMs. In order to reduce variance, I tried to predict using 3 models and take the average of the 3 which sort of gave me better results. After training and validation,I now want to save my model for future forecasts. However, since I have 3 different models, I would like to know if it's possible to merge them into ONE model and then save/load it or if I should save all models one by one and load them later for future predictions?

```py
# fit 3 models
   model1 = fit_lstm(train_scaled, batch_size,nb_epochs, nb_neurons)
   model2 = fit_lstm(train_scaled, batch_size,nb_epochs, nb_neurons)
   model3 = fit_lstm(train_scaled, batch_size,nb_epochs, nb_neurons)

# predict on test set using 3 models
   forecast1 = model1.predict(test_reshaped, batch_size=batch_size)
   forecast2 = model2.predict(test_reshaped, batch_size=batch_size)
   forecast3 = model3.predict(test_reshaped, batch_size=batch_size)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are after an ensemble model.

Something like the following:

```
from keras.models import load_model
models=[]
for i in range(numOfModels):

    modelTemp=load_model(path2modelx) # load model
    modelTemp.name="aUniqueModelName" # change name to be unique
    models.append(modelTemp)


def ensembleModels(models, model_input):
    # collect outputs of models in a list
    yModels=[model(model_input) for model in models] 
    # averaging outputs
    yAvg=layers.average(yModels) 
    # build model from same input and avg output
    modelEns = Model(inputs=model_input, outputs=yAvg,    name='ensemble')  

    return modelEns



model_input = Input(shape=models[0].input_shape[1:]) # c*h*w
modelEns = ensembleModels(models, model_input)
model.summary()
```

Save the ensemble model:

```
modelEns.save(<path_to_model>)
```

Load and predict:

```
modelEns=load_model(<path_to_model>)
modelEns.summary()
y=modelEns.predict(x)
```

[Source](https://medium.com/randomai/ensemble-and-store-models-in-keras-2-x-b881a6d7693f)

Check [this article](https://machinelearningmastery.com/stacking-ensemble-for-deep-learning-neural-networks/) as well.

Comment: do you know what is this line for?                                                           
model_input = Input(shape=models[0].input_shape[1:]) # c*h*w

Comment: Model input should be a tensor with the same shape as input data. For example, in case of image inputs with channel first format: (1,96,128) it will get (96, 128)

Comment: so models[0].input_shape[1:] is the shape of data that I gave to the first model isn't it?

Comment: yes, in other words `models[0].input_shape(rows, columns)`

Comment: yes but it gives me this error: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'lstm_3_input' with dtype float and shape [1,1,1]

Comment: yes, sorry. ignore my previous comment. It should be a tensor! I would imagine something like: `(sequence, row, columns)` or for images `(channel, height, width)`

Comment: I still can't feed the ensemble model the same input data as the other single sub models

Comment: what is the input shape of your other models ? respectively for each one

Comment: all models have input_shape[1:] = (1,1) but what I pass to them is data of shape (28,1,1) for the submodels it works but not the ensemble model even if the both have same input_shape[1:]

Comment: `def fit_lstm(train, batch_size, nb_epoch, nb_neurons): #function I use to create models
    X, y = train[:, 0:-1], train[:, -1]
    X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], 1, X.shape[1])
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(nb_neurons, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, X.shape[1], X.shape[2]), stateful=True))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    for i in range(nb_epoch):
        model.fit(X, y, epochs=1, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0, shuffle=False)
        model.reset_states()
    return model `

Comment: check this post https://towardsdatascience.com/ensembling-convnets-using-keras-237d429157eb it looks like a very similar problem.

Comment: it's similar but doesn't have a focus on my issue unfortunately